# Swap token to ether through Uni-V2 yields Fail with error 'TransferHelper: ETH_TRANSFER_FAILED'

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I have two interfaces:

```
interface IUniswap {
    function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable /*DELETE MAYBE*/ returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);   
}

interface IERC20 {
     function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
     function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
     function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
}
```

I would like to swap some tokens (that the contract already has) into ETH, using the following function:

```
function swapTokenForEth(address token, uint amountIn) external returns (bool) {
    

    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    uint deadline = block.timestamp + 600;

    path[0] = token;
    path[1] = WETH;

    require(IERC20(token).approve(address(uniswap), (amountIn + 10000)), 'Uniswap approval failed');
    uniswap.swapExactTokensForETH(
        amountIn,
        1, //MIN FIXED TO 1 FOR TESTING
        path,
        address(this),
        deadline
    );

    return true;

}
```

The transaction reverts giving the following error:  Fail with error 'TransferHelper: ETH_TRANSFER_FAILED'.

Thanks in advanced for the help.

Comment: Well, does your contract hold `amountIn` tokens right before you execute its `swapTokenForEth` function?

Comment: Yes it does. I am going to concatenate this operation with a swapETHForToken, therefore in the same transaction the contract should:1. Buy tokens, 2. Sell tokens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Router02` [documentation](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/router02/) says that

> If the to address is a smart contract, it must have the ability to receive ETH.

This is exactly the case now, so you have to use the `payable` modifier on your function:

```
function swapTokenForEth(address token, uint amountIn) external payable returns (bool) {
    

    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    uint deadline = block.timestamp + 600;

    path[0] = token;
    path[1] = WETH;

    require(IERC20(token).approve(address(uniswap), (amountIn + 10000)), 'Uniswap approval failed');
    uniswap.swapExactTokensForETH(
        amountIn,
        1, //MIN FIXED TO 1 FOR TESTING
        path,
        address(this),
        deadline
    );

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Must Include the following in your smart contract

`receive() payable external {}`

I Hope This Helps